# Getting "Cannot find module 'request-json/node_modules/request'" while trying to run mocha tests

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, npm-install

I am trying to run mocha tests as below:

```
mocha test\myTest.js
```

However I get below error:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'request-json/node_modules/request'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)....
```

I explicitly tried adding npm dependencies `request` and `request-json` but it did not help. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the latest version of the npm module `request-json` was not installing it required dependencies. I manually did a `npm install` inside this module and that solved the issue.